# jQuery invoice and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a dynamic invoice system for myself. But I can't seem to completely get it working correctly.

I have a invoice table like this in HTML:

Product name -- Quantity -- Tax -- Price (without tax) -- total price

My HTML looks like this:

```
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Item name" class="form-control" /></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="number" min="1" id="target" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control quantity" /></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="text" placeholder="TAX" class="form-control tax" /></td>
<td class="text-right"><input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" /></td>
<td class="text-right"><input type="text" disabled placeholder="0,00" class="form-control price" /></td>
```

I can add rows with this Javascript code:

```
<script>
function addItem(){

    var itemRow =
            '<tr>' +
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item name" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control tax" placeholder="Tax" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" /></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>' +
            '</tr>';

    $("#items_table tr:last").after(itemRow);
}
</script>
```

And I calculate it with this jQuery code:

```
 <script>
    var total = 0;
    var taxTotal = 0;

    (function() {
        $('#items_table').on('change', 'input', function() {
            if( !$(this).hasClass('tax')) {
                totalPrice = 0;

                var row = $(this).closest('tr');

                // ## Get quantity
                var qty = parseFloat(row.find('input:eq(1)').val());

                if (qty < 0) {
                    row.addClass('danger');
                    return;
                } else {
                    row.removeClass('danger');
                }

                // ## Get the entered price
                var price = parseFloat(row.find('input:eq(3)').val());

                if (price < 0) {
                    row.addClass('danger');
                    return;
                } else {
                    row.removeClass('danger');
                }

                // ## Calculate total price
                var total = qty * price;

                // ## Set total price at the end
                row.find('input:eq(4)').val(isNaN(total) ? '' : total);

                tax = parseFloat(row.find('input:eq(2)').val());

                var salesTax = total * (tax / 100);

                if (!isNaN(salesTax)) {

                    $('#tax-' + row.find('input:eq(2)').val()).html(salesTax.toFixed(2));

                    $('#tax_percentage').html(tax + '%');
                    $('#tax_total').html('&euro; ' + salesTax.toFixed(2));

                    $('.price').each(function (i, obj) {
                        // ## Add all the prices again
                        totalPrice = totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).val()) + salesTax;
                    });
                }

                $('#total_price').html('&euro; ' + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
            }else{

                // ## Remove all the taxes
                $('[id^=tax-tr-]').remove();


                if($('#tax-'+ $(this).val()).length > 0 ){
                    console.log('it already exists');
                }else{

                    $('.tax').each(function (i, obj) {
                        var itemRow =
                                '<tr id="tax-tr-' + $(this).val() + '">' +
                                    '<td colspan="4" class="font-w600 text-right">BTW ' + $(this).val() + '%</td>' +
                                    '<td style="width: 20%;" class="text-right">&euro; <span id="tax-' + $(this).val() + '">0</span></td>' +
                                '</tr>';

                        $("#subtotal_table tr").eq(-2).after(itemRow);
                    });

                }

            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Although, its not exactly doing what I want. I want the total price to be at the end of the table row (total price disabled row)

And I want the tax to be added below the invoice (a new table), like this:

Sub total: (Total price without tax)
TAX 10%: (The tax ammount according to the 10%)
TAX 15%: (The tax ammount according to the 15%)
Total: (Sub total price + the tax prices)

But the problem I get is once I have 2 items in the table, and I change the first row's TAX, it gets all messed up.

I am currently out of idea's how to correctly do this. So I all I need is once I filled 1 item row, the tax gets in the total table added, and once I change that tax in that row, it changes below aswell, and the price has to be changed aswell.

Can someone get me back on the right track?

Comment: Can you explain this part a little differently, I don't quite follow what you want to show in the second table?  "Sub total: (Total price without tax) TAX 10%: (The tax ammount according to the 10%) TAX 15%: (The tax ammount according to the 15%) Total: (Sub total price + the tax prices)"

Comment: Do you want to show that breakdown for every row, or just for the row the user is editing?

Comment: Like, each item has its own TAX. This tax is getting added to another table below.

So for example, if I enter a product like:

product name - quantity - tax - price

It would add the tax that I entered below onto the table and the total for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you want to display in the second table,however, I believe the below will suite your needs.

[Here is a jsFiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net/sdLbk80f/5/)

```js
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    addItem();
});
$('#items_table').on('keyup', '.update', function () {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; // if the user hit del or backspace, dont do anything
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) return false;
    calculateTotals();
});
$('#taxPercentage').change(function () {
    calculateTotals(); // user changed tax percentage, recalculate everything
});

function calculateTotals(){
    
    // get all of the various input typs from the rows 
    // each will be any array of elements
    var nameElements = $('.row-name');
    var quantityElements = $('.row-quantity');
    var taxElements = $('.row-tax');
    var priceElements = $('.row-price');
    var totalElements = $('.row-total');
    
    // get the bottom table elements
    var taxPercentageElement =$('#taxPercentage');
    var subTotalElement =$('#subTotal');
    var totalTaxElement =$('#totalTax');
    var grandTotalElement =$('#grandTotal');

    var subTotal=0;
    var taxTotal=0;
    var grandTotal=0;
    $(quantityElements).each(function(i,e){
        
        // get all the elements for the current row
        var nameElement = $('.row-name:eq(' + i + ')');
        var quantityElement = $('.row-quantity:eq(' + i + ')');
        var taxElement = $('.row-tax:eq(' + i + ')');
        var priceElement = $('.row-price:eq(' + i + ')');
        var totalElement = $('.row-total:eq(' + i + ')');

        // get the needed values from this row
        var qty = quantityElement.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, ''); // filter out non digits like letters
            qty = qty == '' ? 0 : qty; // if blank default to 0
            quantityElement.val(qty); // set the value back, in case we had to remove soemthing
        var price = priceElement.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
            price = price == '' ? 0 : price; // if blank default to 0
            priceElement.val(price); // set the value back, in case we had to remove soemthing
    
        // get/set row tax and total
        // also add to our totals for later
        var rowPrice = (price * 1000) * qty
            subTotal = subTotal + rowPrice;
        var tax = taxPercentageElement.val() * rowPrice;
            taxElement.val((tax / 1000).toFixed(2));
            taxTotal = taxTotal + tax;
        var total =   rowPrice + tax
            totalElement.val((total / 1000).toFixed(2));
            grandTotal = grandTotal + total;
    });
    
    // set the bottom table values
    subTotalElement.val((subTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));   
    totalTaxElement.val((taxTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));  
    grandTotalElement.val((grandTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));   
}
function addItem() {
    var itemRow =
        '<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control row-name" placeholder="Item name" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-quantity" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-tax" placeholder="Tax" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-price" placeholder="Price" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control row-total" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $("#items_table").append(itemRow);
}
addItem(); //call function on load to add the first item
```

```css
button{
    font-size:18px;
    
}
.myTable {
    background-color:#ffaa56;
}
.myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:hover td {
}
#items_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
#items_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#ffd0a3;
}
.myTable td {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td {
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}
.myTable tr td:last-child {
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addRow">Add a row</button><br><br>
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items_table"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
    <br>
<table class="myTable" style="width:70%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tax Percentage</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
            <th>Total Tax</th>
            <th>Grand Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items_table">
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="" id="taxPercentage" class="form-control">
                    <option value=".10">10%</option>
                    <option value=".15">15%</option>
                </select>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="subTotal" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalTax" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="grandTotal" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
        
        <p>Add rows and give them values for quantity and price, the script will do the rest.</p> 
        <p>Select a diferent tax amount to recalculate everything</p>
```

Comment: You are really, really close @DelightedD0D, there is only 1 difference.

You can separately give up the tax percentage. In your fiddle you can only select 1 TAX percentage, but this can be different for each item.

So like, your example is really cool, but the tax dropdown, can be different for each item itself, so that has to be added to the item row itself. Still upvote for you though :) (I do not have enough rep tho.. :( )

Comment: Do you want to have a dropdown with several tax percentages on each row, or would you like the user to type in a percentage into a box on each row?

Comment: The last one, the user can type the tax itself

Comment: For a challenge, see if you can update the original jsFiddle to incorporate the changes you need. if you run into trouble,  [here's a new jsFiddle showing how I would do it](http://jsfiddle.net/sdLbk80f/7/)

Comment: I have marked your answer as the solution, thank you for getting met started mate, I can get working on this!! :)

Comment: You're welcome, For a solution with a select for each box, [see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdLbk80f/9/)